# GNU Prolog does not recognize *between* predicate

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am learning Prolog, using GNU Prolog on Mac OS X.  I am getting the following error from interactive mode:

```
GNU Prolog 1.3.1
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2009 Daniel Diaz
| ?- between(0,5,X).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,between/3),top_level/0)
| ?- halt.
```

But `between/3` is supposed to be a built-in predicate, I thought.  Why is this happening and what can I do about it?  Thanks!

Comment: upgrade your installation or take a Prolog definition

Comment: The `between/3` built-in predicate was added to GNU Prolog in version 1.4.1.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you, Paulo!  In fact, I had suspected that, and tried to update gnu-prolog using Homebrew.  Now I can see that I had a couple of problems: (1) I had issued the command "brew reinstall Gnu Prolog," and, apparently, Homebrew has no "reinstall" command (although it looked as if it were doing something--odd); (2) After uninstalling and reinstalling, I eventually found out that Homebrew now installs software in /usr/local/Cellar, but my "gprolog" command was a symlink pointing to something below /opt/usr/local (now I don't remember).  Changing the symlink fixed this.